# Javascript multiple nested if statements don't work with Rails code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a method inside helper which fires an action which changes value of instance variable. Inside my javascript I've done this:

```
if(cat_id == 1)
{
  <% cat_appointments(1) %>
}
else if(cat_id == 2)
{
  <% cat_appointments(2) %>
}
else if(cat_id == 3)
{
  <% cat_appointments(3) %>
}
```

My helper:

```
module StaticHelper
    def cat_appointments(cat_id)
        @appointments = Appointment.where(cat_id: cat_id)
    end
end
```

The problems is that appointments are set like every time there is selected cat with id=3. If I put alert in those conditions, alert with selected id is displayed correctly when user selects specific cat.

Any ideas what is wrong with this code? How to change that variable?

When I replace:

```
else if(cat_id == 2)
{
  <% cat_appointments(2) %>
}
```

with:

```
else if(cat_id == 3)
{
  <% cat_appointments(3) %>
}
```

Then there are not always displayed appointments with cat_id=3. Now there are always displayed events with cat_id=2. So, the last 'else if' statement is always correct.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? :) I set cat_id when user selects an option from drop own menu. Options have id's like cats in database. Appointment is a model from which I select data.

Comment: Oh! I deleted my comment after seeing `If I put alert in those conditions...`, where exactly are you placing the alerts?  Now after reading your comment, I want to say I'm pretty sure you need `cat_id == '1'` (string, not integer value).

Comment: @vinodadhikary - If I place alerts right before <% cat_appointments(x) %>, they are normally executed and I see correct cat id's. I put string value instead of integer but it's still the same.

Comment: how is that JS code being called?  I'm assuming it's an action template for an ajax call.

Comment: No, it's a normal on change call for drop down menu: $("#cat_id").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    setCalendar(selectedVal);
  }); -And setCalendar function contains that code on the beginning and some other code for calendar.

Comment: Oh, I don't think that's going to work because your ruby code is going to get parsed and executed before your js code which is why you are getting appointment for that last line `cat_appointments(3)`.  The js code executes after the server executes the ruby code and sends the response to the client.  I suggest you look into implementing ajax to achieve your goal.

Comment: @vinodadhikary - Can you post your last message (that one with the vote up) as a answer to this question? I will mark is as correct answer. I managed to do it with ajax after all.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that you solved it.  I think it would be beneficial for all if you posted your solution and marked it as answer, I think I just gave a nudge :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `=`

```
<%= cat_appointments(1) %>
```

Comment: Something is not right when I add =. My calendar is now not displayed at all.